# Copy/Move managed disk to another region in azure using powershell

Tags: azure

Is it possible to copy/move azure managed disk from one region to another region in the same subscription?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do with powershell,

Step 1 Create a source storage account for migration.

Step 2: Create a new storage account in the region we want to move to.

Step 3: Create a managed disk under the resource group “Test” within the portal

Step 4: Execute the  PowerShell to copy the blob and get a status.

**[Reference](http://devchat.live/en/2017/11/01/how-to-move-managed-disk-from-one-region-to-another/)**